# android permission denied (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Tags: android, android-permissions

У меня старое приложение есть. где targetSdkVersion 16. В нем есть 2 разрешения,`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. При использовании на девайсе с андроид 7, при записи данных на карту - ошибка permission denied. Но при чтении, такой ошибки нету! Это баг самого андроида? Или совместимости нету?

Comment: Проверьте, может быть разрешения вручную отозваны в настройках приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может попытаться запросить разрешение динамически？Это может быть необходимо для андроида 6+.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

[Здесь документация](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Более полный код с проверкой SDK ус-ва

```
//Проверка версии SDK устройства
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                //динамическое получение прав на WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission is granted");

                    //делаете что-то

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                    //запрашиваем разрешение
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
            } else {
                //делаете что-то;
            }
```

Comment: Знаю я про разрешения, использую для новых приложений. В старых приложений нельзя менять targetSdkVersion. А без этого, запротсить права не получится. Почему не работают старые приложения на новых девайсах. Вот это вопрос. Это, по всей видимости баг Андроида. То что работает на Андроид 4, должно работаь на Седьмом. Если не работает. Значит обратной совместимости нет!

Comment: Вернее просто совместимости

Comment: @Devel0 никакой это не баг, я вам ссылку кинул, вы читали？Грубо говоря, все разрешения делятся на нормальные и опасные. И если для андроид 4 достаточно просто  разместить все разрешения в манифесте, то начиная с андроида 6,  необходимо не только разместить все разрешения в манифесте, но и спрашивать об опасных разрешениях у пользователя. Посмотрите ссылку, там даже полный пример приведен.

Comment: Надо проверять версию sdk телефона прежде чем спрашивать разрешение

Comment: Я обновил ответ, посмотрите, сейчас проверить нет возможности, но это должно помочь

Comment: При targetSdkVersion < 23 разрешения берутся из манифеста на любой версии устройства. У автора targetSdkVersion = 16, значит все разрешения из манифеста были даны при установке. Другое дело, что их можно отозвать вручную через настройки на Android 6+. Поэтому всё равно нужно делать проверки в рантайме.

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо

Comment: @Likhanov что с совместимостью?

Comment: @Devel0 для этого гугл и сделал support библиотеки, в которых портирует новые фичи для старых версий ОС. Что вам и предлагают сделать в ответе (класс `ActivityCompat`). И в документации, на которую также оставили ссылку. Но ведь вы и так "знаете про разрешения..."