# Чтение из внешнего файла Android

Tags: android, android-sdk

Возникла проблема - необходимо использовать набор данных - Dublin Core десятка-двух документов - для будущего анализа в программе. Но тут же возникает проблема, как внести в программу эти данные.
Решил забить их в блокнот вручную по определенному принципу и считывать построчно через программу.
Но каким образом считывать внешний файл я не понимаю. Пробовал несколько видов работы с файлами и потоками, но все упирается в то, что я либо не могу найти файл, либо не могу получить доступ к нему (как и ко всему внешнему хранилищу данных).
Вопрос: как работать с моим файлом из программы или же как получить разрешение на внешнее хранилище.

```
// открытие файла
public void openText(){

    try {
        int permissionStatus = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionStatus != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
                    , 1);
        } else {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/document.txt");
            //InputStream isStream = openFileInput("document.txt");
            //if(isStream != null) {
            FileInputStream fileOutputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileOutputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String str;
            String buffer = "";// = new StringBuffer();
            int j = 0;
            Vector<String> document = new Vector<String>();
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                document.add(str.toString());
                j++;
                if (j >= 15) {
                    j = 0;
                    documents.add(document);
                    document = new Vector<String>();
                }
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch(Throwable t){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_READ_CONTACTS:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openText();
            } else {
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

Тот способ получения разрешения, что в openText() не работает - он почему-то перепрыгивает через него, так и не запрашивая разрешения.
Заранее очень благодарен всем обратившим внимание!

Comment: Начните с разрешений: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview. Вам нужно разрешеение на чтение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754428/238266

Comment: Пожалуйста, удалите ответ из вопроса и оформите его именно как ответ, чтобы людям, которые будут искать решение подобной проблемы проще его нашли

Comment: Теперь все в порядке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал код João Cartucho из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage

Получил следующее:

```
public boolean isStoragePermissionReadGranted() {
    String TAG = "Storage Permission";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean isStoragePermissionWriteGranted() {
    String TAG = "Storage Permission";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Также объявил разрешение только для чтения - заработало в обе стороны и запросило разрешение на работу с внешним хранилищем.
Не особо понял, в чем была загвоздка, и почему раньше андройд не просил разрешения.